# How to list the fields in a particular node-type?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I would like to generate a list of all the fields in a particular node-type.  Looking at the API for content_fields, I tried this:

```
content_fields(NULL, $nodetype);
```

Unfortunately, this returns *all* the defined fields, not just those in my particular $nodetype.

Is there a way to generate a list of all the fields associated with a particular node-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no existing CCK function that does exactly that but it would be very easy to implement your own:

```
function content_fields_by_type($type_name) {
  $type = content_types($type_name);
  return isset($type['fields']) ? $type['fields'] : array();
}
```